# How to fix KeyError: 0 in mycode

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas

I have trouble when implementing fuzzy knn https://github.com/sahilsehwag/FuzzyKNN , when I run k-nearest neighbor it works but not fuzzy

```
def fit(self, X, y=None):
    self._check_params(X,y)
    self.X = X
    self.y = y

    self.xdim = len(self.X[0]) #in here
    self.n = len(y)

    classes = list(set(y))
    classes.sort()
    self.classes = classes

    self.df = pd.DataFrame(self.X)
    self.df['y'] = self.y

    self.memberships = self._compute_memberships()

    self.df['membership'] = self.memberships

    self.fitted_ = True
    return self
```

when I run I get an error

```
File "C: /Users/DELL/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 172, in <module>
     custModel.fit (xTrain, yTrain)

File "C: /Users/DELL/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 53, in fit
     self.xdim = len (self.X [0])

KeyError: 0
```

Comment: What is `X` and does it have `X[0]`?

Comment: I'm guessing you meant `self.X` to be list, but it's actually a dict instead.

Comment: what is X.? A `list` or a `dict` .?

Comment: You can see in here https://github.com/sahilsehwag/FuzzyKNN , more complete code

Comment: From https://github.com/sahilsehwag/FuzzyKNN/blob/master/fuzzy_knn.ipynb it looks all good. So what's the new data you feed into `custModel.fit` that produce this  error?